# MongoDB: Aggregation query on nested array

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I'm now working on real-time open-high-low-close stock price data. I want to find the timestamp of the highest price and lowest price for each stock item.

```py
{   '_id': ObjectId('5d8db3700a1650f211831f16'),
    'isuLists': [   {   'hgprc': 8100,
                        'isuSrtCd': '000020',
                        'lwprc': 8100,
                        'opnprc': 8100,
                        'trdPrc': 8100},
                    {   'hgprc': 0,
                        'isuSrtCd': '000040',
                        'lwprc': 0,
                        'opnprc': 0,
                        'trdPrc': 500},
                    {   'hgprc': 10050,
                        'isuSrtCd': '000050',
                        'lwprc': 10050,
                        'opnprc': 10050,
                        'trdPrc': 10050},
                     ...
                     similar data continues
                     ...
                    {   'hgprc': 0,
                        'isuSrtCd': '700001',
                        'lwprc': 0,
                        'opnprc': 0,
                        'trdPrc': 9305},
                    {   'hgprc': 3310,
                        'isuSrtCd': '900140',
                        'lwprc': 3310,
                        'opnprc': 3310,
                        'trdPrc': 3310}],
    'trdDd': '20190927',
    'trdTm': '090000'
},
...
{   '_id': ObjectId('5d8d51000a1650f211826c9a'),
    'isuLists': [   {   'hgprc': 8130,
                        'isuSrtCd': '000020',
                        'lwprc': 7880,
                        'opnprc': 8100,
                        'trdPrc': 7980},
                    {   'hgprc': 508,
                        'isuSrtCd': '000040',
                        'lwprc': 498,
                        'opnprc': 504,
                        'trdPrc': 500},
                    {   'hgprc': 10050,
                        'isuSrtCd': '000050',
                        'lwprc': 9720,
                        'opnprc': 10050,
                        'trdPrc': 9780},
                     ...
                     similar data continues
                     ...
                    {   'hgprc': 0,
                        'isuSrtCd': '700001',
                        'lwprc': 0,
                        'opnprc': 0,
                        'trdPrc': 9305},
                    {   'hgprc': 3310,
                        'isuSrtCd': '900140',
                        'lwprc': 3230,
                        'opnprc': 3265,
                        'trdPrc': 3300}],
    'trdDd': '20190927',
    'trdTm': '155959'
}
```

the data is accumulated every two seconds from 9:00 to 16:00(take a look at `trdTm` above).

I manged to find out the timestamp of `opnprc` and `clsprc` using the code below, but couldn't find out the timestamp of highest `hgprc` and lowest `lwprc`.

```py
 [
    {"$unwind": "$isuLists"},
    {"$match": {"isuLists.lwprc": {'$gt': 0}}},
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$isuLists.isuSrtCd',
            'opnTm': {'$first': '$trdTm'},
            'clsTm': {'$last': '$trdTm'}
        }
    }
]
```

I want to find `trdTm`(trading time) of the highest `hgprc` and lowest `lwprc` for every `isuSrtCd`(issue code).

How can I find the following output?

`{issue code(isuSrtCd), timestamp(trdTm) of the highest 'hgprc', timestamp(trdTm) of the lowest 'lwprc'}`
for every issue code

```py
[
   {'_id': '000020', 'hgTm': '110233', 'lwTm': '135205'},
   {'_id': '000040', 'hgTm': '142411', 'lwTm': '095233'},
   {'_id': '000050', 'hgTm': '110255', 'lwTm': '140017'},
   ...
   {'_id': '900140', 'hgTm': '105931', 'lwTm': '095329'},
]
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the time for highPrice and LowPrice may not be unique. What that means is the price may high and it may be same for many accumulations. So it will be essentially array.

Below is the query which actually gives me min and max of lowPrice and HighPrice , along with that it gives me the array of timeStamps - when the price was low or high.

```
 db.getCollection('trade').aggregate({"$unwind": "$isuLists"},
   {"$group":{
   "_id":"$isuLists.isuSrtCd",
   "minLowPrice":{$min:"$isuLists.lwprc"},
   "maxHighPrice":{$max:"$isuLists.hgprc"},
   "timeStamp":{"$push": 
   {date:"$trdDd",time:"$trdTm",highPrice:"$isuLists.hgprc",lowPrice:"$isuLists.lwprc"}}
   }},{"$project":
   {
   "sourceCode":"$_id",
   "lowPriceAndTime": { $filter:{input:"$timeStamp",as:"time",cond:{$eq: 
   ["$$time.lowPrice","$minLowPrice"]}}},
   "highPriceAndTime": { $filter:{input:"$timeStamp",as:"time",cond:{$eq: 
   ["$$time.highPrice","$maxHighPrice"]}}}
   }
})
```

Comment: I modified your query a little bit, and it worked. Although this query requires more memory and takes more time, I  really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$isuLists"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$isuLists.isuSrtCd",
            "min_stock":{
                $min:{
                    "lwprc":"$isuLists.lwprc",
                    "trdTm":"$trdTm"
                }
            },
            "max_stock":{
                $max:{
                    "hgprc":"$isuLists.hgprc",
                    "trdTm":"$trdTm"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "hgTm":"$max_stock.trdTm",
            "lwTm":"$min_stock.trdTm"
        }   
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8db3700a1650f211831f16"),
    "isuLists" : [
        {
            "hgprc" : 8100,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000020",
            "lwprc" : 8100,
            "opnprc" : 8100,
            "trdPrc" : 8100
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 0,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000040",
            "lwprc" : 0,
            "opnprc" : 0,
            "trdPrc" : 500
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 10050,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000050",
            "lwprc" : 10050,
            "opnprc" : 10050,
            "trdPrc" : 10050
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 0,
            "isuSrtCd" : "700001",
            "lwprc" : 0,
            "opnprc" : 0,
            "trdPrc" : 9305
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 3310,
            "isuSrtCd" : "900140",
            "lwprc" : 3310,
            "opnprc" : 3310,
            "trdPrc" : 3310
        }
    ],
    "trdDd" : "20190927",
    "trdTm" : "090000"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8d51000a1650f211826c9a"),
    "isuLists" : [
        {
            "hgprc" : 8130,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000020",
            "lwprc" : 7880,
            "opnprc" : 8100,
            "trdPrc" : 7980
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 508,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000040",
            "lwprc" : 498,
            "opnprc" : 504,
            "trdPrc" : 500
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 10050,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000050",
            "lwprc" : 9720,
            "opnprc" : 10050,
            "trdPrc" : 9780
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 0,
            "isuSrtCd" : "700001",
            "lwprc" : 0,
            "opnprc" : 0,
            "trdPrc" : 9305
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 3310,
            "isuSrtCd" : "900140",
            "lwprc" : 3230,
            "opnprc" : 3265,
            "trdPrc" : 3300
        }
    ],
    "trdDd" : "20190927",
    "trdTm" : "155959"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9331cef2e6411a68a145eb"),
    "isuLists" : [
        {
            "hgprc" : 8030,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000020",
            "lwprc" : 10,
            "opnprc" : 8100,
            "trdPrc" : 7980
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 508,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000040",
            "lwprc" : 498,
            "opnprc" : 504,
            "trdPrc" : 500
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 10050,
            "isuSrtCd" : "000050",
            "lwprc" : 9720,
            "opnprc" : 10050,
            "trdPrc" : 9780
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 0,
            "isuSrtCd" : "700001",
            "lwprc" : 0,
            "opnprc" : 0,
            "trdPrc" : 9305
        },
        {
            "hgprc" : 3310,
            "isuSrtCd" : "900140",
            "lwprc" : 3230,
            "opnprc" : 3265,
            "trdPrc" : 3300
        }
    ],
    "trdDd" : "20190927",
    "trdTm" : "155960"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : "900140", "hgTm" : "155960", "lwTm" : "155959" }
{ "_id" : "000020", "hgTm" : "155959", "lwTm" : "155960" }
{ "_id" : "700001", "hgTm" : "155960", "lwTm" : "090000" }
{ "_id" : "000040", "hgTm" : "155960", "lwTm" : "090000" }
{ "_id" : "000050", "hgTm" : "155960", "lwTm" : "155959" }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your query is so simple, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Oh, I realized that your query didn't get the right hgTm and lwTm...

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma. You are passing both price and time to $min or $max so it is 'anding' time n price then giving that

Comment: @Lucia As per MongoDB document comparison rule, It would first compare ```lwprc``` and only goes for comparison of ```trdTm``` if the previous is same.

Comment: Thus if maximum `hgprc` exists multiple times, the maximum `trdTm` would be selected from those and if minimum `lwprc` exists multiple times, the minimum `trdTm` would be selected from those. @SungpyoCho isn't it what you wanted?